How to retrieve all rows from a virtualized table in Playwright? Only the displayed rows exists in the html
I am working with a web application that uses a virtualized table. The table updates its DOM as you scroll, meaning only the rows currently visible on the screen are present in the DOM at any given time. I need to retrieve all the rows from this table, not just the ones currently displayed.  Here is a simplified version of my current code:
# Locate the table body element
tbody_element = page.locator('.virtual-table-body-list')

# Retrieve all rows currently in the DOM
rows = tbody_element.locator('.rt-tr-group.rt-tr-group.table-tr-group').all()

This code only retrieves the rows that are currently visible. How can I modify it to scroll through the table and collect all rows?
Additional Information:
I am using Playwright with Python.
The table is scrollable and updates the DOM dynamically as you scroll.
I need a solution that ensures all rows are retrieved, regardless of their visibility on the screen.



Please share the web application, or a reproducible example of it, along with your full code. Without that, it's pretty much impossible to help. What's a "virtualized table"? I'd wager the data is probably coming through a network request, so you can just intercept that and minimize having to mess with the page itself.

Hi @ggorlen, I can't share the app (Or URL), since it's the company platform. I added one more screenshot where you can see the HTML structure that I described.

Sorry, I can't automate images. The CSS and JS behavior matters, in addition to the HTML structure, and even if you had it all together, see Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?. I'd have to retype all that in. Try creating a reproducible example. Otherwise, I think you'll see people will just make random guesses, adding answers that aren't even in the right language or library and you likely won't get a satisfactory answer.

@ReaHaas Can you please take a look at my solution and let me know if its helpful to you.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78969070/1831456

This is a very generic scenario which is faced in lot of modern applications these days. We should n't be asking specific site info to start with to provide any solution.

It's not generic. It's specific to one site OP is automating. I can virtually guarantee your answer won't work for OP on multiple levels.

Are you saying concept of lazy loading specfic to user's application? I am not sure about your exposure on actual playwright projects, but it's pretty common these days in modern applications.

I have used multiple times this in multiple projects myself in last couple of months .It's called lazy loading in case you are not aware of.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

@ggorlen I agree with Vishal Agarwal.
This is a generic behavior, of a table that updates the HTML on scrolling to only display the visible data. The solution is not bound to a specific app or language and should be generic.

@ReaHaas You agree with Vishal, but apparently the "generic" solution that was provided doesn't work for you. So now that nobody has satisfactorily answered this in the past 4 days, you might consider the possibility that it's not so generic after all. Sure, many sites have scrolling, and unloading older results from the scroll window is also common, but the exact nature of that scrolling is highly variable and site-specific. There are myriad details that can break a script. This definitely needs a [mcve] and an actual site. Like I said, probably intercept the network responses.

@ReaHaas If the behavior is generic and you can't share your page, then please create a simple, runnable example page that encompasses the behavior. Then I have something I can run and verify so I can write a definitive answer that works for that use case (and it'll be up to you to adapt it to your actual site, which may not be an easy task if it turns out there are any differences between your contrived example and the real world use case).

@ReaHaas The project I'm working on has similar JS async stuff going on. What I ended up doing is that I monitor the network traffic and I simply wait for network responses. I'd check the network tab and take notes what calls should be waited for. See page.expect_response.  https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response
